# How to search in particular level in JSON tree using Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to learn a method of searching within a JSON tree on a particular level. I have the following JSON template example:

```
"Pair": {
    "Instrument_A": {
        "Segment A": {
            "default": {
                "value X": 1,
                "value Z": 2,
                "value Y": 3,

            }
        },
        "Segment B": {
            "default": {
                "value X": 1,
                "value Z": 2,
                "value Y": 3,

            }
        }
    },
    "Instrument_B": {
        "Segment A": {
            "not-default": {
                "value X": 1,
                "value Z": 2,
                "value Y": 3,

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to count all arrays with the name that does not equal to "**default**", for example, you can see on the 4 level under instrument B, Segment A, there is an object named "**not-default**"

Comment: Do you really have duplicate keys `Instrument_A` in your example - as those wont be preserved interpreting it using the `json` parser...

Comment: `not_default` is an object not an array.

Comment: @JonClements  I have edited the body of the JSON example, in this JSON I have Many Pair's, in each Pair I have several Instruments, in each instrument I have several Segments. the instruments are not recurring in same Pair.

Comment: @SamerAbuGahgah Edited (thanks)

Comment: Is this the full JSON?

Comment: @Neo in the full JSON I have multiple Pair's with Multiple instruments that have multiple Segments

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json using `json` package and iterate through the dictionaries.

Python2:

```
import json
json_str = "..."
json_object = json.loads(json_str)
for pair_k, pair_v in json_object.iteritems():
    for inst_k, inst_v in pair_v.iteritems():
        for seg_k, seg_v in inst_v.iteritems():
            if not seg_v == "default"
                pass # do whatever you want - print, append to list, etc.
```

Python3:

```
import json
json_str = "..."
json_object = json.loads(json_str)
for pair_k, pair_v in json_object.items():
    for inst_k, inst_v in pair_v.items():
        for seg_k, seg_v in inst_v.items():
            if not seg_v == "default"
                pass # do whatever you want - print, append to list, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = Counter()

def count_keys(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key != 'default':
                count[key]+=1
            count_keys(data[key])

count_keys(data)
print(count)
```

prints

```
Counter({'value X': 3, 'value Z': 3, 'value Y': 3, 'Segment A': 2, 'Pair': 1,'Instrument_A': 1, 'Segment B': 1, 'Instrument_B': 1, 'not-default': 1})
```